# enable maximize button on window.open() in c# web form

Tags: javascript, c#, popupwindow

I am using a popup window. When it opens it has only minimize and close button enable, maximize button is disable. I want to enable maximize button also.
Here is the code.

```
 var params = 'width=' + screen.width/1.02;
           params += ', height=' + screen.height/1.1; 
 window.open('DailyAttendancePopUp.aspx', '_blank', params+', dependant=no, location=0, alwaysRaised=no, menubar=no,toolbar=no, status=no');
```

Comment: it is working fine in Chrome and IE, but if you facing problem you can put *resizable=1* or *resizable=yes* in options.

Comment: This issue is not related to C#. Is Javascript and html related.

Answer (score 1):

you can put `resizable=1` or `resizable=yes` in options

your code will be like that

```
window.open('DailyAttendancePopUp.aspx', '_blank', params+', dependant=no, location=0, alwaysRaised=no,resizable=yes, menubar=no,toolbar=no, status=no');
```